# Guardar el valor del text input en una base de datos

Tags: python, base-de-datos, kivy

Necesito guardar el valor del text input en una base de datos sqlalchemy desde el boton `enviar`:

```
class Clientes(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super(Clientes, self).__init__()
        self.app = app
        self.orientation= 'vertical'
        rect = Rectangle(source= ('imagenes/fondo.jpg'), size= (2000,1800))
        self.canvas.add(rect)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Nombre', font_size = 30, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.8}, size_hint= (None, None), size=(150, 100)))
        self.Nombre = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.8}, size_hint= (None, None), size=(500, 100))
        self.add_widget(self.Nombre)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Apellido', font_size = 30, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.6}, size_hint= (None, None), size=(150, 100)))
        self.Apellido = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.6}, size_hint= (None, None), size=(500, 100))
        self.add_widget(self.Apellido)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Correo Electronico', font_size = 30, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.4}, size_hint= (None, None), size=(150, 100)))
        self.Di = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.4}, size_hint= (None, None), size=(500, 100))
        self.add_widget(self.Di)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Producto que necesita', font_size = 29, pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.2}, size_hint= (None, None), size=(150, 100)))
        self.Pro = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.2}, size_hint= (None, None), size=(500, 100))
        self.add_widget(self.Pro)
        self.add_widget(Button(text='Enviar', pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.05}, size_hint= (None, None), size=(100, 30)))

class ComercioApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PantallaPrincipal(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ComercioApp().run()
```

Comment: FjSevilla sabes?

Comment: Hola Cristian, bienvenido a [es.so]. No das información de como tiene implementada la base de datos, pero simplemente asocia una callback al botón y en ella realizas la operación con la bd, en la documentación tienes un ejemplo: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html. El contenido del text input lo consigues simplemente con `self.Pro.text`

Comment: ahi lo vere soy principiante y de a poco voy aprendiendo gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El proceso básico pasaría por crear una callback (un método/función) que sea llamado cuando el botón <kbd>Enviar</kbd> se pulse. Esto se consigue usando el método `bind` para enlazar el evento correspondiente (`on_press`) con el callable que debe ser llamado cuando el evento tenga lugar:

```
def callback(btn):
    pass

mi_botón.bind(on_text=callback)
```

En esta callback solo tienes que acceder al texto de cada `TextInput` usando su atributo `text` y con toda la información hacer la operación con la base de datos.

No proporcionas información sobre la estructura de tu base de datos, pero realmente esto ya no tiene que ver con Kivy, te dejo un ejemplo reproducible muy simple usando sqlite como prueba:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle

from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


Base = declarative_base()


class Pedido(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pedidos'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    nombre = Column(String)
    apellido = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)
    producto = Column(String)


class Clientes(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, app, bd_session):
        super(Clientes, self).__init__()
        self.app = app
        self._session = bd_session

        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        #rect = Rectangle(source=('imagenes/fondo.jpg'), size= (2000,1800))
        #self.canvas.add(rect)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Nombre',
                              font_size = 30,
                              pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.8},
                              size_hint= (None, None),
                              size=(150, 100)
                              ))
        self.inp_nombre = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.8},
                                size_hint= (None, None),
                                size=(500, 100)
                                )
        self.add_widget(self.inp_nombre)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Apellido',
                              font_size = 30,
                              pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.6},
                              size_hint= (None, None),
                              size=(150, 100)
                              ))
        self.inp_apellido = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.6},
                                      size_hint=(None, None),
                                      size=(500, 100)
                                      )
        self.add_widget(self.inp_apellido)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Correo Electronico',
                              font_size = 30,
                              pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.4},
                              size_hint=(None, None),
                              size=(150, 100)
                              ))
        self.inp_correo = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.4},
                                    size_hint= (None, None),
                                    size=(500, 100)
                                    )
        self.add_widget(self.inp_correo)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='Producto que necesita',
                              font_size = 29,
                              pos_hint={'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.2},
                              size_hint= (None, None),
                              size=(150, 100)
                              ))
        self.inp_producto = TextInput(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.8, 'center_y': 0.2},
                                      size_hint=(None, None),
                                      size=(500, 100)
                                      )
        self.add_widget(self.inp_producto)
        self.btn_enviar = Button(text='Enviar', 
                                 pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.05},
                                 size_hint= (None, None), size=(100, 30)
                                 )
        self.btn_enviar.bind(on_press=self.hacer_pedido)
        self.add_widget(self.btn_enviar)

    def hacer_pedido(self, instance):
        nombre = self.inp_nombre.text
        apellido = self.inp_apellido.text
        correo = self.inp_correo.text
        producto = self.inp_producto.text

        pedido = Pedido(nombre=nombre, apellido=apellido, email=correo, producto=producto)
        s = self._session()
        s.add(pedido)
        s.commit()
        s.close()


class ComercioApp(App):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._engine = create_engine('sqlite:///tienda.sqlite')
        self._session = sessionmaker()
        self._session.configure(bind=self._engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self._engine)

    def build(self):
        return Clientes(self, self._session)

    def on_stop(self):
        self._engine.dispose()
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ComercioApp().run()
```